# Excel ExportAsFixedFormat PDF

Tags: c#, excel-2007

I can successfully take an excel file and export it as a PDF file in c#

```
private static void ExportWorkbookToPDF(string workbook, string output)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workbook) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot create PDF copy " +
            "from empty workbook.");
    }

    Application excelApplication = new Application();
    excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;
    excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excelApplication.Visible = false;

    Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + 
        "\\" + workbook);

    if (excelWorkbook == null)
    {
        excelApplication.Quit();
        excelApplication = null;
        excelWorkbook = null;

        throw new NullReferenceException("Cannot create new excel workbook.");
    }

    try
    {
        excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, 
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + 
            "\\" + output);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    finally
    {
        excelWorkbook.Close();
        excelApplication.Quit();
        excelApplication = null;
        excelWorkbook = null;
    }
}
```

What parameter or object do I need to access in order to save the excel file as page width instead of page height?

Comment: Page width and height are properties of a printer.  You don't deal with that when you generate the pdf, the user selects it when *printing* the pdf.  Picking Landscape mode, typically.  Trying to do it early would generate a serious case of neck cramp.

Comment: Page width and height as far as a PDF doc goes, do not need to use printers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found the property required to force the export of your workbook in a PDF with Landscape view.

```
try 
{ 
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)  
    excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet).PageSetup.Orientation =  
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;

    excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,  
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + 
        "\\" + output); 
}
```

Comment: @bl4kh4k I am the one who should thanks you. I have never thinked  to do that and solved an annoying problem of mine

Comment: If you have multiple worksheets, use the property excelWorkbook.Sheets to access them. Using a loop, check if it's of type 'Chart' or 'Worksheet' before casting, and then change the orientation per item.

Comment: I don't know. I suggest to post a question about it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install The 2007 Microsoft Office Suite Service Pack 3 (SP3)
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27838
2. Install 2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7

**Mandatory :** Set **Microsoft XPS Document Writer** as default printer in server. 
Because **ExportAsFixedFormat** function executes **Microsoft XPS Document Writer** to convert Excel to PDF.

This is working for me.

Comment: Service pack is not necessary for that. Install just the add-in. If the Add-In is not installed, Excel is so intelligent that it will throw an "Invalid Parameter" exception!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
string paramExportFilePath = @"C:\Test2.pdf";
Excel.XlFixedFormatType paramExportFormat = Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF;
Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality paramExportQuality = Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard;
bool paramOpenAfterPublish = false;
bool paramIncludeDocProps = true;
bool paramIgnorePrintAreas = true;
if (xlWorkBook != null)//save as pdf
    xlWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFormat, paramExportFilePath, paramExportQuality,     paramIncludeDocProps, paramIgnorePrintAreas, 1, 1, paramOpenAfterPublish, misValue);
```

Parameter `paramIgnorePrintAreas=true` resizes the page.